# cesium api clone and development how to use requirejs what is dependency of cesium

Tags: javascript, requirejs, cesiumjs

I want to clone cesium git and changing javascript files.I dont want to add minified file is Build/Cesium.js  I want to use separeted javascript files.
My code

```
   <script data-main="scripts/main" src="../ThirdParty/requirejs-2.1.9/require.js"></script>

  <style>
      @import url(../Source/Widgets/widgets.css);
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="cesiumContainer"></div>
  <script>
  require(["Widgets/Viewer/Viewer"], function(util) {
    //This function is called when scripts/helper/util.js is loaded.
    //If util.js calls define(), then this function is not fired until
    //util's dependencies have loaded, and the util argument will hold
    //the module value for "helper/util".
    var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
});
```

Error:

```
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Cesium.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Cesium
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/GlobeFS.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/GlobeFS
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/GlobeFSDepth.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/GlobeFSDepth
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/GlobeFSPole.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/GlobeFSPole
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/GlobeVS.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/GlobeVS
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/GlobeVSDepth.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/GlobeVSDepth
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/GlobeVSPole.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/GlobeVSPole
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/SkyAtmosphereFS.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/SkyAtmosphereFS
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/SkyAtmosphereVS.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/SkyAtmosphereVS
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/SkyBoxFS.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/SkyBoxFS
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/SkyBoxVS.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/SkyBoxVS
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/SunFS.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/SunFS
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/SunTextureFS.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/SunTextureFS
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/SunVS.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/SunVS
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/BillboardCollectionFS.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/BillboardCollectionFS
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/BillboardCollectionVS.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/BillboardCollectionVS
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/CustomSensorVolumeFS.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/CustomSensorVolumeFS
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/CustomSensorVolumeVS.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/CustomSensorVolumeVS
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/SensorVolume.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/SensorVolume
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/Materials/BumpMapMaterial.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/Materials/BumpMapMaterial
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/Materials/CheckerboardMaterial.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/Materials/CheckerboardMaterial
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/Materials/DotMaterial.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/Materials/DotMaterial
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/Materials/FadeMaterial.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/Materials/FadeMaterial
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/Materials/FresnelMaterial.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/Materials/FresnelMaterial
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/Materials/GridMaterial.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/Materials/GridMaterial
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/Materials/NormalMapMaterial.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/Materials/NormalMapMaterial
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/Materials/PolylineArrowMaterial.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/Materials/PolylineArrowMaterial
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/Materials/PolylineGlowMaterial.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/Materials/PolylineGlowMaterial
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/Materials/PolylineOutlineMaterial.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/Materials/PolylineOutlineMaterial
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/Materials/ReflectionMaterial.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/Materials/ReflectionMaterial
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/Materials/RefractionMaterial.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/Materials/RefractionMaterial
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/Materials/RimLightingMaterial.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/Materials/RimLightingMaterial
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/Materials/StripeMaterial.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/Materials/StripeMaterial
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/Materials/Water.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/Materials/Water
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/PolylineCommon.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/PolylineCommon
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/PolylineFS.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/PolylineFS
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/PolylineVS.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/PolylineVS
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/Appearances/AllMaterialAppearanceFS.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/Appearances/AllMaterialAppearanceFS
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/Appearances/AllMaterialAppearanceVS.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/Appearances/AllMaterialAppearanceVS
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/Appearances/BasicMaterialAppearanceFS.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/Appearances/BasicMaterialAppearanceFS
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/Appearances/BasicMaterialAppearanceVS.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/Appearances/BasicMaterialAppearanceVS
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/Appearances/TexturedMaterialAppearanceFS.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/Appearances/TexturedMaterialAppearanceFS
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/Appearances/TexturedMaterialAppearanceVS.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/Appearances/TexturedMaterialAppearanceVS
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/Appearances/PerInstanceColorAppearanceFS.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/Appearances/PerInstanceColorAppearanceFS
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/Appearances/PerInstanceColorAppearanceVS.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/Appearances/PerInstanceColorAppearanceVS
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/Appearances/PerInstanceFlatColorAppearanceFS.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/Appearances/PerInstanceFlatColorAppearanceFS
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/Appearances/PerInstanceFlatColorAppearanceVS.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/Appearances/PerInstanceFlatColorAppearanceVS
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/Appearances/PolylineColorAppearanceVS.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/Appearances/PolylineColorAppearanceVS
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/Appearances/PolylineMaterialAppearanceVS.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/Appearances/PolylineMaterialAppearanceVS
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/EllipsoidFS.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/EllipsoidFS
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/EllipsoidVS.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/EllipsoidVS
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/ViewportQuadVS.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/ViewportQuadVS
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/PostProcessFilters/FXAA.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/PostProcessFilters/FXAA
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/AdjustTranslucentFS.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/AdjustTranslucentFS
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/CompositeOITFS.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/CompositeOITFS
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/PostProcessFilters/AdditiveBlend.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/PostProcessFilters/AdditiveBlend
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/PostProcessFilters/BrightPass.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/PostProcessFilters/BrightPass
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/PostProcessFilters/GaussianBlur1D.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/PostProcessFilters/GaussianBlur1D
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/PostProcessFilters/PassThrough.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/PostProcessFilters/PassThrough
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/ReprojectWebMercatorFS.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/ReprojectWebMercatorFS
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/ReprojectWebMercatorVS.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/ReprojectWebMercatorVS
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:163
GET file:///C:/Users/eesirik/Desktop/cesium-master/Apps/scripts/Shaders/Builtin/CzmBuiltins.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND require.js:1881
Uncaught Error: Script error for: Shaders/Builtin/CzmBuiltins
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

It says need Cesium.js   but I want to work at development mode.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the Cesium Sandcastle examples are fully functional RequireJS applications that you can use as an example of how to properly reference the Source tree as AMD modules.

For example:

https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/blob/master/Apps/Sandcastle/gallery/Cesium%20Widget.html

Take note of the call to `require.config` that sets `baseUrl`.  Then when the `Cesium` module is required, it is found in the `Source` folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">  <!-- Use Chrome Frame in IE -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="description" content="Use the Viewer Widget to start building new applications or easily embed Cesium into existing applications.">
    <meta name="cesium-sandcastle-labels" content="Beginner, Showcases">
    <title>Cesium Demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Sandcastle-header.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../ThirdParty/requirejs-2.1.9/require.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    require.config({
        baseUrl : '../../../Source',
        waitSeconds : 60
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body class="sandcastle-loading" data-sandcastle-bucket="bucket-requirejs.html" data-sandcastle-title="Cesium + require.js">
<style>
    @import url(../templates/bucket.css);
</style>
<div id="cesiumContainer" class="fullSize"></div>
<div id="loadingOverlay"><h1>Loading...</h1></div>
<div id="toolbar"></div>
<script id="cesium_sandcastle_script">
require(['Cesium'], function(Cesium) {
    "use strict";

    // Cesium.CesiumWidget is similar to Cesium.Viewer, but
    // is trimmed down.  It is just a widget for the 3D globe;
    // it does not include the animation, imagery selection,
    // and other widgets, nor does it depend on the third-party
    // Knockout library.
    var widget = new Cesium.CesiumWidget('cesiumContainer');

    Sandcastle.finishedLoading();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The CesiumViewer reference application, located in Apps\CesiumViewer is a standalone requireJS based Cesium application you can use as a starting point.